# From Navier–Stokes equations to Euler, Bernoulli, etc

Tags: fluid-dynamics, applied-physics, navier-stokes

How can one go from the 3D compressible [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) to the simpler [Euler equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29), [Bernoulli's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) and other fluid dynamic equations?

Comment: This is a pretty good quick reference: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/fluid-mechanics-equations-d_204.html If you want a detailed treatment, Anderson's 'Fundamentals of Aerodynamics' treats the subject quite well, going into detail about the accuracy of each model under different Mach and Reynold's numbers.

Comment: Any fluid dynamics textbook (Acheson, Kundu & Cohen, etc) should cover this information.

Comment: Even CFD by Anderson is a good reference.